# Tkinter: String variables not working

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have made a program for science which asks you a symbol of n element and you must type in the element but the problem is that it can't tell if you got the answer wrong it just keeps saying CORRECT!,

Here is my code,

```
# Import Modules
from tkinter import *
import random, time

# Window Setup
root = Tk()
root.title('Element Finder')
root.state('zoomed')

# Elements

"""

a = H, Hydrogen

b = He, Helium

c = O, Oxygen

d = C, Carbon

e = N, Nitrogen

f = Ne, Neon

g = U, Uranium

h = Na, Sodium

i = Ar, Argon

j = K, Potassium

k = Mg, Magnesium

l = Cl, Chlorine

m = B, Boron

n = Au, Gold

o = Pd, Palladium

p = Kr, Krypton

q = Ca, Calcium

r = Pm, Promethium

s = Ag, Silver

t = Rb, Rubidium

u = Y, Yurium

v = Ir, Iridium

w = Pt, Platnium

x = Ti, Titanium

y = Hg, Mercury

z = Er, Erbium

"""

# Variables
element = StringVar()
guess = StringVar()
answer = StringVar()

def question():
    guess.set('')
    element.set('')
    r = random.randint(1, 26)
    if r == 1:
        element.set('H')
    elif r == 2:
         element.set('He')
    elif r == 3:
        element.set('O')
    elif r == 4:
        element.set('C')
    elif r == 5:
        element.set('Ne')
    elif r == 6:
        element.set('U')
    elif r == 7:
        element.set('Na')
    elif r == 8:
        element.set('Ar')
    elif r == 9:
        element.set('K')
    elif r == 10:
        element.set('Mg')
    elif r == 11:
        element.set('Cl')
    elif r == 12:
        element.set('B')
    elif r == 13:
        element.set('Au')
    elif r == 14:
        element.set('Pd')
    elif r == 15:
        element.set('Kr')
    elif r == 16:
        element.set('Ca')
    elif r == 17:
        element.set('Pm')
    elif r == 18:
        element.set('Ag')
    elif r == 19:
        element.set('Rb')
    elif r == 20:
        element.set('Y')
    elif r == 21:
        element.set('Ir')
    elif r == 22:
        element.set('Pt')
    elif r == 23:
        element.set('Ti')
    elif r == 24:
        element.set('N')
    elif r == 25:
        element.set('Hg')
    elif r == 26:
        element.set('Er')

def check():
    e = element.get()
    g = guess.get()
    if e == 'H' and g == 'Hydrogen' or 'hydrogen' or 'HYDROGEN':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'He' and g == 'Helium' or 'helium' or 'HELIUM':
        answer.set('Correct')
    if e == 'O' and g == 'Oxygen' or 'oxygen' or 'OXYGEN':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'C' and g == 'Carbon' or 'carbon' or 'CARBON':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Ne' and 'Neon' or 'neon' or 'NEON':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'U' and g == 'Uranium' or 'uranium' or 'URANIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Na' and g == 'Sodium' or 'sodium' or 'SODIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Ar' and g == 'Argon, argon' 'ARGON':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'K' and g == 'Potassium' or 'potassium' or 'POTASSIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Mg' and g == 'Magnesium' or 'magnesium' or 'MAGNESIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Cl' and g == 'Chlorine' or 'chlorine' or 'CHLORINE':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'B' and g == 'Boron' or 'boron' or 'BORON':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Au' and g == 'Gold' or 'gold' or 'GOLD':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Pd' and g == 'Palladium' or 'palladium' or 'PALLADIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Kr' and g == 'Krypton' or 'krypton' or 'KRYPTON':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Ca' and g == 'Calcium' or 'calcium' or 'CALCIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Pm' and g == 'Promethium' or 'promethium' or 'PROMETHIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Ag' and g == 'Silver' or 'silver' or 'SILVER':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Rb' and g == 'Rubidium' or 'rubidium' or 'RUBIDIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Y' and g == 'Yurium' or 'yurium' or 'YURIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Ir' and g == 'Iridium' or 'iridium' or 'IRIDIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Pt' and g == 'Platnium' or 'platnium' or 'PLATNIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Ti' and g == 'Titanium' or 'titanium' or 'TITANIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'N' and g == 'Nitrogen' or 'nitrogen' or 'NITROGEN':
        answer.set(g + ' is correct')
    if e == 'Hg' and g == 'Mercury' or 'mercury' or ' MERCURY':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    if e == 'Er' and g == 'Erbium' or 'erbium' or 'ERBIUM':
        answer.set('Correct!')
    else:
        answer.set('Incorrect.')
    question()

# Question
Label(root, text='What element has the symbol:', fg='black', font='20').pack(side=TOP)
e = Label(root, textvariable=element, fg='blue', font='20').pack(side=TOP)
a = Entry(root, textvariable=guess, font=20).pack(side=TOP)
Button(root, text='Check', fg='green', command=check).pack(side=TOP)
c = Label(root, textvariable=answer, font=20, fg='blue').pack(side=TOP)
question()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not “Yurium” but rather “[Yttrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttrium)”…

Comment: Let's see: 1) Using lower() to reduce the number of choices to 1 is a trick that HAS NEVER BEEN USEFUL TO ANYONE ELSE STUDYING PYTHON.  2) Turning a series of if statements into a dictionary lookup will NEVER BE HELPFUL TO ANYONE ELSE studying python.  A.Roda, Inbar Rose, Frank van Puffelen, plaes, and Lichtamberg please ban yourselves for being completely incompetent.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `'g == Hydrogen' or 'hydrogen' or 'HYDROGEN'`you can do `g.lower() == 'hydrogen'`

The issue here is:

```
if g == 'Hydrogen' or 'hydrogen' or 'HYDROGEN'
```

evaluates as

```
 if (g == 'Hydrogen') or ('hydrogen') or 'HYDROGEN'
```

The latter parts of the expression always evaluate to `True` Hence the error.

You can simplify your code a great deal by creating a dictionary:

```
d = {1: 'H', 2: 'He', ... }
```

and replace the huge chunk of `if` with `element.set(d.get(r))`

Comment: This was very helpful but i don't know how to make dictionaries.

Comment: @user2318122, my_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}; print my_dict["a"].  Try it.  Each entry in a dictionary has a "key" and a "value", which are separated by a colon.  And each entry is separated by a comma. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
g == 'Hydrogen' or 'hydrogen' or 'HYDROGEN'
```

All those statements are wrong.  You have to write:

```
g == "Hydrogen" or g == "hydrogen" or g == "HYDROGEN"
```

But it's easier to write:

```
g.lower() == "hydrogen"   #added '()' per Blender's comment
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you can get rid of all those if statements like this:

```
import random as r

atomic_symbols = ["H", "He", "O"]
rnum = r.randint(0, len(atomic_symbols) - 1 )
element.set(atomic_symbols[rnum])
```

And:

```
answers = {
    "H": "hydrogen", 
    "He": "helium", 
    "O": "oxygen"
}

if guess.get().lower() == answers[element.get()]:
    answer.set("Correct")
```

The flip side is you have to create a big list and a big dictionary with all the values.  Actually, to save some typing just create the dictionary, and then use keys() to get a list of all the atomic symbols.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried this and it works perfectly.